# Add WebPart to display a link above a modern library in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx-webparts

When the company I am working for migrated from SP2013 to SP Online, they migrated to the classic experience.  As we move forward years later, they are using the  modern experience per my push.  There is a library where they would like a link to a document with instructions to be added above the library. This was available in SP 2013/2010 where we could edit the page and add a web part.  How can this be done in the modern experience?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the Pin to Top option that is displayed in the ribbon when focusing on the document to promote.  It's not ideal as it cuts off the name of the document but it is a work around.

Comment: This is the recommended approach for featuring or linking documents directly within your document library. Alternatively, you can also create a page with text and/or links to a document /8or even embed the document directly) alongside the library webpart. This will give you a more customizable experience closer to what you had previously but it will be separate from the direct library page which may not be ideal.